# Is there a way to combine angular with existing php/js/html web project?

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I'm working with an existing old web project, and want to start using angular 7 in the project from now on, mostly in order to not stay behind with old tech. The server side is php 7, and client is html + javascript (using jQuery). Server is Apache.

I want to continue using php for server side, and start using angular for client side.

I've tried to find information but couldn't find anything useful.

My question is: Is it possible to add angular to the code from now on, while the old pages continue working using their current code (regular js and html pages)? can I add angular to my project and work with it from now on, without making too big changes in the existing code? If so, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very scant on detail and code, and to help you, please first help us by improving your question. Tell the details, show the pertinent code, preferably a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, and most important, write your question with your audience in mind -- think "what will they need to know to fully understand my problem and code and be able to help me"

Comment: @Rohan Khude, I'm new to Stack Overflow, so if you could help me with what information should I add, thanks

Comment: If you are new to Angular then you should firstly try how it works and what the structure looks like. Also it's not recommend to use jQuery with Angular only if it's necessary.

Comment: @Josef Katič  thanks, I'm familiar with angular, new to here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Unlikely

It will be very tough.

Angular is a complete full-fledged web framework that includes a [bootstrapping process](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping) which makes it very difficult to integrate with an existing project.

You could consider using something like [React](https://reactjs.org/) instead. Because it is not a framework (just a view library) it is easier to integrate with existing code and has support for gradual adoption.

React has even included [a small tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) that adresses this issue